# Find data in shared memory

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

I am using shared memory and a mutex object. I am quite new to this shared memory topic and the c++-winapi. I have two applications. Application A is a GUI-App, which is prepared for shared memory usage. In this application I need to store the adress for a boolean data type in a gui dialog and I picked 'M0.0' as address. The other application is a cpp visual studio console application. In my main.cpp-file am able to grab shared memory and mutex-object. Anyway I have no idea how to grab the data related to M0.0. How do I find this data in the memory?

Comment: "M0.0" doesn't mean anything.  You locate variables by their offset from the start of the shared memory region.  The first one starts at offset 0.  A struct is always a good way to get started.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - please give me further information, that I am able to search for related tutorials. Currently I am not able to detect the next action to 'use' your reply.

Comment: Use the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/html).  Improve it by using a struct instead of a string.

Comment: Storing an address in the shared memory will not work. Application A and B each have a unique memory space and an address that is valid in one of them is meaningless in the other. The shared memory can share data, but not addresses.